# Ubuntu 20.04 does not shutdown

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire V3-371-53S4 laptop and when trying to shutdown it hangs and the only way to shutdown is pressing the power button for long time. I've checked kern.log and syslog and I do not find anything. Any idea?

I attach the logs of the shut down:

[image: Shutdown-logs]

Comment: Silly question, but do you have an external HDD or a USB drive connected to the computer when shutting down? If so, entry-level Acer (and some Asus) notebooks have a habit of killing power to the USB ports before the hard disks have been cleanly unmounted, which can result in lockups. Your display shows that `/` was remounted as read-only during the shutdown process, which is highly irregular.

Comment: No, I have a Windows partition but no USB is attached. Yes, I noticed that `/` was also remounted, and I could understand why.